# Joint density of functions of two random variables

Tags: probability, random-functions

If $X$ and $Y$ are iid with $U(0,2)$, $Z=2X+Y$ and $V=e^X$
What is the joint density of $(Z,V)$?

$\begin{align}
V=e^X &\Rightarrow X=lnV\\
Z=2X+Y &\Rightarrow Y=Z-2lnV
\end{align}$

$
J=
\begin{vmatrix}
\frac{\partial x}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} \\ 
\frac{\partial y}{\partial z} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} \\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
0 & \frac{1}{v} \\
1 & -\frac{2}{v}
\end{vmatrix}
=-\frac{1}{v}
$

$\begin{align}
f_{Z,V}(z,v)&=f_{X,Y}(lnV,Z-2lnV)*|J| \\
&=f_X(lnV)f_Y(Z-2lnV)*|-\frac{1}{v}|
\end{align}$

$\begin{align}
0 \le lnV \le 2 &\Rightarrow 1 \le V \le e^x \\
0 \le Z-2lnV \le 2 &\Rightarrow 2lnV \le Z \le 2+2lnV \\
&\Rightarrow 0 \le Z \le 6
\end{align}$

For $1 \le v \le e^x$ and $0 \le z \le 6$,
$\begin{align}
f_{Z,V}(z,v)&=\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{2}*\frac{1}{v} \\
&=\frac{1}{4v}
\end{align}$

However, when I check the answer by using double integration
$\begin{align}
\int_{1}^{e^2} \int_{0}^{6}\frac{1}{4v} \,dz\,dv &= \frac{3}{2}\int_{1}^{e^2}\frac{1}{v} \,dv\\
&=\frac{3}{2}*(2-0) \\
&=3
\end{align}$

The integral of density by the support should instead be 1, that means my answer is wrong, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed $Z\in [0,6]$, but if $\varphi $ is s.t. $\varphi (X,Y)=(U,V)$, then it's not true that $$\varphi(\{(X,Y)\in (0,2)^2\})= [1,e^2]\times [0,6].$$ What you nevertheless have is $$\varphi (\{(X,Y)\in (0,2)^2\}=\{(V,Z)\mid V\in (1,e^2), 2\ln(V)\leq Z\leq 2\ln(V)+2\}).$$

Comment: Thanks so much, I got your point. Although X and Y is independent, U and V is not independent. So the support of {U,V} is not a rectangle

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$0<\log V<2$$

$$0<Z-2\log V <2$$

That is

$$2\log V<Z<2\log V+2$$

Graphically, $(V,Z)$ domain is the following

[image]

Concluding:

$$f_{VZ}(v,z)=\frac{1}{4v}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(1;e^2)}(v)\cdot\mathbb{1}_{(2\log v;2(1+\log v))}(z)$$